# ¿ireconocimiento de java build path?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Estoy queriendo iniciar un proyecto con Spring , pero cuando lo creo me aparece los siguientes errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya configure el build path manualmente indicandole  la ruta.Cual seria otra solucion?

Comment: ¿Has probado borrando la carpeta 5.0.12.Final y después `mvn clean install` de nuevo?

Answer (score 0):

la verdad existen varias opciones , yo lo que te recomiendo es que elmines el directorio y cuando le des click  derecho al proyecto. Luego de eso vas a la parte de maven y sigues el cursos con la flechita ">" y le das a updateproject y para finalizar no te olvides que tienes que darle a force snpashopts . Asi te resolvera el problema